# NativeScript - how to view the contents of the app settings while debugging?

Tags: angular, local-storage, nativescript, storage

I'm writing an app with NativeScript 6+ and Angular 8+.

I will need to use some client-side storage to save some data so that it will persist each time the user uses the app.

I have read about it here:

https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-framework-modules/application-settings

https://www.nativescript.org/blog/client-side-storage-in-nativescript-applications

I'm going to use 'app settings'.

When I am developing and debugging, I want to be able to view and edit the contents of the app settings. How can I do this?

Comment: You could print them (or put a breakpoint) anywhere you like (e.g. something like `console.log(getBoolean("isTurnedOn"))`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to look into all these keys. You may use `getAllKeys()` method on [application-settings](https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-framework-modules/application-settings) module to get all active keys, then get value of each key, log it if you want while debugging.